# Manually set up library version for Angular project created with `ng new`

Tags: angular, angular-cli, package.json

I used Node `v18.18.2` and `@angular/cli@15.2.9` to create an Angular project with `ng new` command.

rxjs ~7.8.0 appears in package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^15.2.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.12.0",
    "spa-ui-common": "spa-ui-common-2.0.6.tgz"
  },
```

My project depends on a module which supports Angular 15. below is part of the package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/cdk": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/common": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/core": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/localize": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/material": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/router": "^15.2.9",
    "@babel/core": "^7.21.8",
    "@electron/remote": "2.0.10",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.10.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "6.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "5.13.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "5.13.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^14.2.0",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.7",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.1",
    "core-js": "3.30.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "handlebars": "^4.7.7",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment-mini": "^2.29.4",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.43",
    "papaparse": "^5.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.5",
```

After I added the module into my package.json and run `npm install` conflict is found for `rxjs`

pm ERR! Found: rxjs@7.8.1
npm ERR! node_modules/rxjs
npm ERR!   rxjs@"~7.8.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer rxjs@"^6.5.3 || ^7.4.0" from @angular/core@15.2.10

~7.8.0 from my project and ^6.5.5 from the module.

As far as I know, Angular 15 supports rxjs ^6.5.3 || ^7.4.0 https://angular.io/guide/versions

Then can I just manually change the rxjs version in my project package.json, to like ^6.5.3 to remove the compatibility issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are absolutely allowed change the versions in your package.json file.  The worst thing that could happen is you get another dependency error, which you already have,

It should be noted that changing from ^6.5.5 to ^6.5.3 will have no effect on which package is actually installed as they should both use the highest available 6.x.x

It looks like your project still has 7.8.1 installed even though the package.json file was downgraded.  I would quickly check the package-lock.json just to be sure it has the right version and then definitely check your node_modules folder, for the project not global.

Go to the rxjs folder (in node_modules) and look at that package.json and it will show you the exact version that is installed.  If it is still on 7.x.x then you'll need to reinstall your packages.  If it is on 6.x.x it will probably be closer to 6.6.7 since the ^ allows for minor and patch updates.

Comment: Btw, your dependencies can easily be cleaned up by simply deleting the node_modules folder and running `npm_install`